# Android Studio: where did "Install Client Libraries" go for Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

Back when I was using Android Studio 0.8.2, whenever I would make a change to an Google Cloud Endpoint in my App Engine backend for an Android project, I would then go to

Tools->GoogleCloudTools->InstallClientLibraries

which generated and installed (wrote them to a local maven repository) the client libraries.

That feature is no longer there in 0.8.9.  How do I generate/install endpoint client libraries now?  Where did that tool go?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two options here :

. You can call the gradle task directly "appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibraries"

. You can try using the new flow by including a configuration in your android build file

```
dependencies {
  compile project(path: '<appengine-module>', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

which will automatically depend on client libraries defined in your app engine module and include any necessary dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @loosebazooka.  what is the purpose of the "configuration" item in compile?  Will it still use the local maven repository?

Comment: With a little more gradle research, I see that a dependency configuration is defined as a named set of dependencies, defined here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html.  In any case, any more details you can add @loosebazooka would be appreciated.

Comment: So the "configuration" here is an artifact (a compiled jar of the client libs) and it's dependencies (google api client dependencies) from the appengine project.  By referencing the configuration in your dependencies, you're telling the android module to include that configuration form the appengine project when you compile and gradle handles pulling in the dependency (there is no maven intermediate here).  Take a look at the build/artifacts directory in your appengine project, you're likely to see one for the appengine project and one for endpoints that you're exporting.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this all makes sense and the new flow works and is cleaner than using "appengineEndpointsInstallClientLibraries". If you think this question and your answer add something useful to the forum please consider up-voting the question.